# searching same items in row in array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

i am trying to make a game like a candy crush or bejeweled, but i had a problem with find a same items in row.
i have this

```
public void mapfinder() {
    int typ = -1;
    int pocet = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            if (plocha[x][y].getgem() == typ) {
                pocet++;
            } else if (pocet > 2) {
                while (pocet > 0) {
                    pocet--;
                    plocha[x][y - pocet] = new Actor(x, y, nogem);
                }
            } else {
                typ = plocha[x][y].getgem();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

acctualy, its slow and i often get outOfArrayExeption

any ideas?

Comment: the `OutOfBound` is most likely a combination of `y=1`, `pocet = 3`, access index `-2`, throw `outOfBound`.

Comment: soo, you suppose to make a more IF for out of bound exeptions?

Comment: how about a using a while instead of for?

Comment: That wont make a difference, because the error occurs most likely at `plocha[x][y - pocet] = new Actor(x, y, nogem);`, where `y-pocet` is most likely to be < 0